# Is there a rule in eventBridge to not accept an event that has particular field, anything-but does not seem to work?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

Is it possible in AWS eventBridge to define a rule that when we see a value in an eventBridge field, we will not process this event? For example, if we have something like:

```
  A: [
    {"name": "name1"},
    {"name": "name2"},
    {"name": "name3"},
  ]
```

What I wanted to do was as long as the array A has an object that has name as "name1", we will not accept this event from the eventBridge to emit. How will we be able to do that? I have tried "anything-but", but it seems like what it does was as long as the array A in the event have anything that is not "name1", eventBridge will emit even if array A in that event has "name1" as name for one of the object.